# Is it possible to make only one dynamic table for event source in prooph cqrs?

Tags: cqrs, prooph

Is it possible to make only one dynamic table for event source in prooph CQRS + ES, instead of creating a new table for each ID?

I am using this tutorial https://pilsniak.com/cqrs-es-php-prooph/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a **SingleStreamStrategy** instead of the AggregateStreamStrategy used in the tutorial.

Read more about [Persistance Strategies](http://docs.getprooph.org/event-store/implementations/pdo_event_store/variants.html#3-2-1-2-5) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. The example link https://github.com/prooph/proophessor-do/blob/master/scripts/create_event_stream.php not working. Could you provide me an example?

Comment: https://github.com/prooph/proophessor-do/blob/master/scripts/create_event_streams.php

Just use "event_stream" (or whatever you prefer as name) and use that name in the repository configuration: https://github.com/prooph/proophessor-do/blob/master/config/autoload/prooph.global.php#L47

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexandar.